# What is association relationship in terms of coding?

Tags: associations

There are 6 relationship in UML diagrams. These are association, dependency, aggregation, composition, generalization, realization. I learned some of them from [a blog site](http://usna86-techbits.blogspot.com.tr/2012/11/uml-class-diagram-relationships.html). But I want to learn the background of these relationship. I mean the reflection of these uml relationship to code. The blog site contains some java codes about these uml relationship. For example;

```
public class A {

    private B _b;

    public void setB(B b) { 
           _b = b; 
    }
```

The above code represents aggregation. Like this, could you give me an example of association relationship as java code? (The blog site doesn't contain association relationship)

Comment: Looking at the blog site IMO what it calls dependency and what you call association are essentially the same.

Comment: I don't think so. Dependecy is showed with dashed line in uml diagram, while association is showed with solid line in uml diagram. That is to say, these are different.